# How to code a graph and its relationships (unweighted graph)

Tags: java

I have been given an Analysis of algorithms group project in which we are tasked to create a recommendation system for a list of persons. We have been given 2 files, a list of people with their information and a list of people along with the activity they are involved in. we are to make recommendations based on who is considered a close contact and if the person waved privacy. A close contact is a person who shares the same community, school, or employer. If a person requested privacy then no recommendations are to be sent to that person. I have loaded the files into a class object but I have hit a roadblock on how to structure the data after the capture. I do not know how to code a graph and from my understanding and visualization of the problem, I believe a graph is the appropriate data structure for this problem. I will attach my code for how I captured the data and the format for the files below.

File formats:

Activity File:

```
Winston, William, Bought Samsung Galaxy Watch 4 
Thomas, Williams, Watching Blackout on Netflix 
John, Warren, Bought Samsung Galaxy Watch 4
Tanisha, Thompson, Listening I'll be with You by Grace Thrillers
Owen, Mendez, Bought FitBit Charge 5
```

Person File:

```
Rajay, Mccalla, 3151288155, RaMccalla38@gmail.com, Hope Flat, Pap High, eGov, Bronks, N
```

Code:

```
public class InfoReader {

    public void ReadInfo(){
        //find file with person data
        try {
            String fileLocation = File.separator + "Users" + File.separator + "user" + File.separator + "Downloads" + File.separator + "SamplefilePersons2022Oct31text.csv";

            File personList = new File(fileLocation);
            //scanner to read from file
            Scanner personScanner = new Scanner(personList);

            while (personScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String nextline = personScanner.nextLine();
                // split file into parts
                String[] personComponents = nextline.split(",");
                //get components of Persons
                String firstname = personComponents[0];
                String lastname = personComponents[1];
                String phone = personComponents[2];
                String email = personComponents[3];
                String community = personComponents[4];
                String school = personComponents[5];
                String employer = personComponents[6];
                String privacy = personComponents[7];

                //creating new person
                Person newPerson = new Person();

                //set data attributes for persons as we read from file
                newPerson.setFirstname(firstname);
                newPerson.setLastname(lastname);
                newPerson.setPhone(phone);
                newPerson.setEmail(email);
                newPerson.setCommunity(community);
                newPerson.setSchool(school);
                newPerson.setEmployer(employer);
                newPerson.setPrivacy(privacy);
                //System.out.println(newPerson);

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        //find file with activity data
        try {
            String fileLocation = File.separator + "Users" + File.separator + "user" + File.separator + "Downloads" + File.separator + "SamplefileActivities2022Oct31text.csv";

            File activityList = new File(fileLocation);
            //scanner to read from file
            Scanner activityScanner = new Scanner(activityList);
            while (activityScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String nextLine = activityScanner.nextLine();
                // split file into parts
                String[] activityComponents = nextLine.split(",");
                //get components of Persons Activities
                String firstname = activityComponents[0];
                String lastname = activityComponents[1];
                String Activity = activityComponents[2];
                //creating new person activity
                Activities newActivity = new Activities();
                //set data attributes for persons as we read from file
                newActivity.setFirstname(firstname);
                newActivity.setLastname(lastname);
                newActivity.setActivity(Activity);
                //System.out.println(newActivity);
            }
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask an actual question. Please [edit] the post and add a focused question.

Comment: If you question should be "*How do I implement a graph ADT?*", then I recommend reading some tutorial. [The wikipedia article on graph ADT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

> It appears you are not storing read Persons, and activities in while
> loops.

**Step 1**
decalare 2 ArrayLists (one for persons, and one for Activities) as:

```
ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList()
ArrayList<Activities> activities = new ArrayList()
```

**Step 2**
store Persons and activities read from files:
in First loop reading person after  newPerson.setPrivacy(privacy); add line

```
persons.add(newPerson);
```

In second loop reading acvities  add

```
activities.add(newActivity);
```

**Step 3**
then search persons, and activities arrayList and match contacts using for loop

Comment: Thank you. This help to receive the data in a more usable format.